# rails unobtrusive login

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am building a blog-like site for a university project using rails 3.2.8 and i would like to implement an unobtrusive login system using the modal box from twitter bootstrap. I have tried some tutorials on the subject but i can't get it to work so far. In the sessions controller i have this:

### sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end

# Handling authentication when user submits login form
# with authenticate method. If the authentication is
# successful stores a permanent or temporary cookie based
# on selection :remember_me with an authorization token
# and redirects to root_url with notice else displays
# alert and redirects to new
def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    if user
        if params[:remember_me]
            cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
        else
            cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
        end
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
    else
        flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
        render "new"
    end
end

# Deleting cookie and redirecting to root_url on
# logout with notice
def destroy
    cookies.delete(:auth_token)
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
    end

end
```

and in the application view i have created a hidden modal where the contents of the form partial should be rendered and `a :remote => true` to the login link

### application.html.erb

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id = "modal">
<div class="modal-body">
</div>
</div>
.
.
.
<%= link_to(log_in_path, :remote => true) do %>
<i class="icon-check"></i> Log in
<% end %>
```

Finally in /app/views/sessions there is the js view

### new.js.erb

```
$("#modal-body").html(<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'form')%>);
$('#modal').modal('show');
```

But instead of showing the login form in the modal rails sends me to the login page (`new.html.erb`). Can anyone help me with this?